# How to install python packages with all dependencies offline via pip3?

Tags: installation, python3, pip, dependencies

first of all I have managed to install Ansible on a server which has no internet access. But I wonder if my approach is correct.

At first I downloaded the necessary dependencies via `pip3`.

```
pip3 download ansible -d .
```

This resulted in the following files downloaded:

```
ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz                          
cryptography-2.8-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl  
MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl  
PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz
cffi-1.13.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl  
Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl                
pycparser-2.19.tar.gz                              
six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Now that I have made these files available on my remote computer, I tried to use

```
pip3 install ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz
```

to install ansible.

This resulted in the following error:

```
Processing ./ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x7f00726f9ef0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/jinja2/
```

So I tried to install Jinja2 manually:

```
pip3 install jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

But this did not work either:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
 broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
0x7fd303a23940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': 
/simple/markupsafe/
```

After Markupsafe was installed, Jinja2 could be installed as well. In the end with `pip3 install ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz` I successfully installed ansible.

Now my question is. Is there a way to tell `pip` to use the downloaded files to install the dependencies or is there an easier approach to install a specific python package with all its dependencies offline?

Thanks for your help and best regards.
yabberth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell `pip` to use the downloaded files to install the dependencies or is there an easier approach to install a specific python package with all its dependencies offline?

I believe what you're looking for are the [--no-index](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-no-index) and [--find-links](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#install-find-links) options to `pip install`. Per the official `pip install` option documentation:

> --no-index
>
> Ignore package index (only looking at --find-links URLs instead).
>
> -f, --find-links
>
> If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives. If a local path or file:// url that’s a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

With these options you can do ex. local installation:

```
pip3 install --no-index --find-links /some/path <package name>
```

or remote installation (e.g. via HTTP):

```
pip3 install --no-index --find-links http:\\remotes\server <package name>
```

In your case, you should be able to simply use `ansible` for the package name ex.:

```
pip3 install --no-index --find-links /some/path ansible

pip3 install --no-index --find-links http:\\remotes\server ansible
```

Though the full file name can be used if you wish:

```
pip3 install --no-index --find-links /some/path ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz

pip3 install --no-index --find-links http:\\remotes\server ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz
```

Assuming all the required dependencies reside in the same location (as listed in your original question), they should be installed as normal (i.e. without having to install each dependency in order manually).

---

**Requirements**

Another option might be to make a requirements file with the proper dependency installation order e.g.:

*ex. requirements.txt*

```
/path/to/MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
/path/to/Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
/path/to/ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz
# ...
```

Then use e.g. `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to install the listed packages. You could use e.g. HTTP links again as well:

*ex. requirements.txt*

```
http:\\remotes\server\MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl 
http:\\remotes\server\Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
http:\\remotes\server\ansible-2.9.4.tar.gz
# ...
```

The clear drawback here is that, assuming one package is dependent on another, you already need to know the order in which certain packages need to be installed.

---

**Other URL Options**

You may also want to look at the [version control system (VCS) section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support) of `pip install` documentation, which offers examples of combining `pip install` with VCS links (i.e. Git, Mercurial, Subversion and Bazaar).

---

References

*[pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/)*

*[pip install (options)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options)*

Answer (score 1):

Since you needs is not to have a full mirror, I would suggest to use **python-pypi-mirror** :

1- Install python-pypi-mirror using pip on a server that have internet connection.

2- Install http.server python module on this server.

3- Create a directory that will server your pip packages.

4- Download the needed packages using python-pypi-mirror to the directory recently created and exposed as an http server (it will contain all its dependencies).

5- Install the needed package remotely.

```
 pip3 install --trusted-host <http_server> -i http://<http_server>:<http.server_default_port>/simple <package_name>
```

[You will find all the needed instructions here](https://pypi.org/project/python-pypi-mirror/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesnt work with my environment. I can only copy files to it via SCP. Nevertheless it may be useful for somebody else.